# Parchment paper and crumb crusts?

Tags: parchment, crumb-crust

I have fallen in love with America's Test Kitchen's recipe for lemon cheesecake. Animal crackers in a crumb crust...who knew? It's really good. I just made it for the second time as a birthday gift for a friend. I didn't want to part with my springform pan, so I cut up her cheesecake and packed it in a plastic lined pizza box. When I was done, half the crust remained stuck to the base of the pan. What a shame as that is a really good crust. It was like each cut sliced through the base leaving a thin layer of crust behind and a thin layer attached to the cheesecake. It occurred to me that it would have been a whole lot better if I had used parchment cut to fit the base of the pan and then transferred the whole cheesecake at once. That splitting of the crust happened the first time I made I made the recipe too. I've never seen a crumb crust recipe that used parchment, but now it *seems* like a no-brainer - so much so that I wonder if I'm missing a key point. Is there a reason this generally isn't done? Do you know or can you think of any reason that it wouldn't work?

Comment: http://cakecentral.com/t/705480/how-do-i-give-away-a-cheesecake-without-my-springform-pan

Comment: Somebody on that thread recommended replacing the bottom of the springform pan with a cardboard cake round. Wow...I think I like the concept of lining the pan with parchment better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have baked crusts with parchment paper underneath several times - it works like a charm!

Comment: Thank you. I haven't made a cheesecake since posting the question, but I'll definitely do the parchment next time I do. It's great to hear from someone who has actually done it. Did you cut the parchment to size, line upwards in the pan, or attach the springform ring with the edges of the parchment sticking out of the pan?

Comment: I cut it to size.

Comment: Fabulous. That's what I'll do next time.

Answer (score 3):

there! I just came across your post and wanted to share the secret to getting the crust off of your springform pan in one perfect piece, with all of it intact. Ready for it?!

...The base of the pan is upside down when it's packaged! I'm not sure why they do that, but I have bought many springform pans and they all come that way. I don't know why, but it really is rather ridiculous. Especially because, as you have learned, you end up leaving half of your crust behind. So, if you flip the base over, it's a bit raised and your entire crust will come off very easily, especially if you have a cake lifter. I never line the bottom crust with parchment paper because it's not necessary when the base is turned the correct way.

Good luck!  :-)